# failing to load model named "Project name"

Tags: ios, core-data

Edit: I added my code below

I'm facing this error, which drives me crazy. Previously, I had an error message that said:

> libc++abi.dylib terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)

and found a solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMi5lPetGy4&t=220s

However, I now have this error message:

> 2017-01-15 21:44:39.059880 بزنسي[27654:918259] [error] error:  Failed
>   to load model named DreamLister CoreData: error:  Failed to load model
>   named DreamLister 2017-01-15 21:44:39.191 بزنسي[27654:918259] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of
>   NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and

DreamLister isn't the app i'm trying to run. So, I don't know why it's being shown when I'm trying to run a different app!!

بزنسي is the name of the app that i'm having the issue with.

```
import UIKit
class ItemDetailsVC: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var storeName: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var initialBalance: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var income: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var salaries: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var tools: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var maintinance: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var otherExpenses: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var expensesTotal: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var totalAftersubtractingExpenses: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var saveBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var calBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var orderForExpenses: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var borderForTotalAfterCalc: UIImageView!

var storeToEdit: Store?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    }

    // border for expenses
    orderForExpenses.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    orderForExpenses.layer.borderWidth = 2
    orderForExpenses.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

    // border for total after subtracting expenses
    borderForTotalAfterCalc.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    borderForTotalAfterCalc.layer.borderWidth = 2
    borderForTotalAfterCalc.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0


    // border for calButton
    calBtn.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    calBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    calBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

    // border for saveBtn
    saveBtn.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    saveBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    saveBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

    if storeToEdit != nil{
        loadStoreData()
    }
}

@IBAction func calButton(_ sender: Any) {

     /*let value1 = Double(income.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let value2 = Double(salaries.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let value3 = Double(tools.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let value4 = Double(maintinance.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let value5 = Double(otherExpenses.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let sum = value1 - ( value2 + value3 + value4 + value5)

    print("result is: \(sum)")*/



    let textFields = [income, salaries, tools, maintinance, otherExpenses]
    var sum = 0.0
    for textField in textFields {
        if let number = Double((textField?.text!)!) { //checks that it is not nil AND a Double
            sum += number
        }
    }

    expensesTotal.text = String(sum)
    // print("result is: \(sum)")
}



@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {

    var store:Store!

    if storeToEdit == nil{

        store = Store(context: context)

    }else {

        store = storeToEdit
    }

    if let storeName = storeName.text{

        store.storeName = storeName
    }

    if let income = income.text{

        store.totalIncomeForStore = store.totalIncomeForStore + (income as NSString).doubleValue
    }

    ad.saveContext()

    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

func loadStoreData(){

    if let store = storeToEdit{

        storeName.text = store.storeName
        initialBalance.text = "\(store.totalIncomeForStore)"
    }
}



@IBAction func deletePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if storeToEdit != nil{

        context.delete(storeToEdit!)
        ad.saveContext()
    }

    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}   
}




import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,    NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var controler: NSFetchedResultsController<Store>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate   = self
    tableView.dataSource = self




    // generateTestData()
    attemptFetch()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    if let sections = controler.sections{

        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    return 0
}


// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell
    configureCell(cell: cell, indexpath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)

    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: ItemCell, indexpath: NSIndexPath){

    let store = controler.object(at: indexpath as IndexPath)
    cell.configureCell(store: store)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let obj = controler.fetchedObjects, obj.count > 0{

        let store = obj[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ItemDetailsVC", sender: store)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "ItemDetailsVC" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ItemDetailsVC{
            if let store = sender as? Store{
                destination.storeToEdit = store
            }
        }
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if let sections = controler.sections{
        return sections.count
    }

    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 86
}

func attemptFetch(){

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Store> = Store.fetchRequest()

    let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSort]

    let controler = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    controler.delegate = self

    self.controler = controler

    do{
        try controler.performFetch()
    }catch{

        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error)")
    }
}


func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

    tableView.beginUpdates()

}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    switch(type){

        case.insert:
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath{
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        break

        case.delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath{
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        break

        case.update:
            if let indexPath = indexPath{
                let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ItemCell
                configureCell(cell: cell, indexpath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
            }
        break

        case.move:
            if let indexPath = indexPath{
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath{
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)                    
            }
        break


    }

}

func generateTestData() {

    let store = Store(context: context)

    store.storeName = "محل رقم ١"

    let store2 = Store(context: context)

    store2.storeName = "محل رقم٢"

    let store3 = Store(context: context)

    store3.storeName = "محل رقم ٣"

    ad.saveContext()
}
```

}

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

Comment: Your exception suggests that your app looking for CoreData model name `DreamLister` which seems to be missing in the app, add it, it should work.

Comment: I appreciate your comment but the thing DreamLister is totally different app. i don't remember adding anything with the name "DreamLister". It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Open your Coredata, there must be something related to `DreamLister`.

Comment: I opened to check the entities i have, I only have two entities ( one called Store and the other one called OverallTotal). Store has two properties. OverallTotal has non. Is there anything else I should check?

Comment: Search of term `DreamLister`

Comment: @user2066392 okay. I'm not that good with **swift** code. But one thing I noticed, _what's your **Store** class?_

Comment: What have you done here? Can you be more elaborate by documenting self code? Inside `func attemptFetch()`?

Comment: this function will get info stored in the batabase stored in core data

Answer (score 2):

Check your AppDeligate, it probably has the line
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DreamLister")

Note that whatever this is called must match the actual core data models name (the name you used when you first created the core data model).  So in this case the name would be DreamLister.xcdatamodel

Answer (score 0):

If you have any third party classes in your project first check that.  Search file name in your project if you found any name then search on internet and add it to you project.

Second if you don't found any link in your project then go to preferences-> Location -> Derived data -> Click on arrow and delete all derived data from there. Clean your project and build it again.

Comment: I did that. but there were no derived data. I mean, i didn't see any file what so ever. Any other suggestion?

Comment: When you open derived data i, did you see new files creating instantly after deleting files.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your

```
+ (nullable NSEntityDescription *)entityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
```

or

```
+ (__kindof NSManagedObject *)insertNewObjectForEntityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
```

method calling lines in anywhere in your project. It might be something like

> you may have used **DreamLister** as your `entityName`.

Comment: The thing is I don't have either functions in my code. Got any other possibility I did wrong?

Comment: @user2066392 then it's tough to say exactly unless you share your source code 

Comment: I just posted my code. I really hope that will help coz it's driving me crazy!!